# Xcode 6 Can't change signing profile

Tags: ios, xcode

I have exactly the same question as the question here: [Xcode 6 - How to pick signing certificate/provisioning profile for Ad-Hoc distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056144/xcode-6-how-to-pick-signing-certificate-provisioning-profile-for-ad-hoc-distri)

I've regenerated a profile which I downloaded and have installed but whenever I try and export to an ipa to upload to Testflight, I can't change the profile it wants to sign the ipa with and am forced to sign it with the XC provisioning profile. How can I change this? And if I wanted to install Xcode 5 to sign it off with, I can't seem to see how to do that?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the old Testflight then just install their [Desktop App](https://testflightapp.com/desktop/download/46/) and use it for uploading your test version. It lets you chose a provisioning profile and even generates the IPA for you.

Comment: That does't actually resolve the issue though. Especially when said Desktop app is in beta.

Comment: I use it for more than a year and it works without any problems.  -- If you also cannot pick your provisioning profile in the Testflight app then there's an issue with your profile. Maybe you don't have the necessary developer certificate. Is your profile listed in `XCode > Preferences > Accounts > (your account) > View Details` after hitting refresh? Are signing identities listed? -- I also recommend to use a *development* provisioning profile for ad-hoc testing. They're much easier to handle cause less problems since you can sign them with your own dev certificate instead of with the admin's