# IPA file for testing purpose

Tags: ios

I am able to archive the project but it is asking for options like Save for Ad-hoc deployment. I have to deliver the IPA to my client and I have their .p12 file, developer certificate and provisioning profile.
What should I fill in the Ad- hoc deployment credentials?
Can I use mine account credentials? I dont have their credentials.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6, it looks like it will automatically go and generate the provisioning profiles for you, based on the account.  Best solution at this time appears to be installing Xcode 5.1.1 and using that Organizer version.

Check out this question here: [Xcode 6 - How to pick signing certificate/provisioning profile for Ad-Hoc distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056144/xcode-6-how-to-pick-signing-certificate-provisioning-profile-for-ad-hoc-distri)