# Provisioning Profile Issue in Xcode 6 (duplicate)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, provisioning-profile

I have been working on iPhone application development when i try to use my already existing provisioning profile that is working well in Xcode 5 will misbehave.
My development provisioning profile replace with production and it will automatically chose Xc:....
type provisioning profile 
and also become production release.

Any Idea what is going on?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056144/xcode-6-how-to-pick-signing-certificate-provisioning-profile-for-ad-hoc-distri

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to [Apple Developer Page](http://developer.apple.com) and find the distribution `provisioning profile` you want to use.
2. Select it, click **Edit**, re-name the profile, and click **Generate**.
3. Download the `provisioning profile` to the Desktop and drag it onto the `Xcode 6` icon.
4. Re-start `Xcode 6`.
5. Open the organizer window and click **Submit** on the archive you built. Xcode will automatically pick your explicit profile instead of the generic one.

Comment: not working for me.. every time i shows None in provisioning profile column.

Answer (score 0):

Download the iPhone Configuration Utility:
http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465

1. Close xCode.
2. Open iPhone Configuration Utility and click on Provisioning Profiles on the left side.
3. Delete the autogenerated ones and make sure your existing one is downloaded.
4. Restart xCode.

When you build again, it should use your old one.

Comment: nt working for me... I did the same steps but every time it shows "None" while exporting archive for Adhoc