# Xcode 6 - Can't pick signing certificate/provisioning profile for Ad-Hoc distribution. Always taken default

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

To distribute the app we are using Xcode 6.0.1, where we encountered some issues by using the following process:

- Added App-Id and distribution provision profile under developer program.
- Chose provision profile under build settings and Archive application.
- Chose Export option to do Ad-HocDistribute.

But with Xcode 6.0.1, this workflow was changed a bit. I couls still select the Ad-Hoc distribution option, but I cannot select the provisioning profile which I have created under developer program against my App-ID. There were no listing of provisional profile as we use to do in Xcode 5 version.

The Xcode 6.0.1 has tried to match the provisional profile from the dev-program and it returns message as no matching certificate and it automatically created identity as XC Ad Hoc * profile. Once I chose the Export option the XC Ad Hoc* profile has been created automatically under the distribution provision profile option in dev-program.

Under the provision profile all devices has been selected which I have added and listing total devices under my testflight application. Please assist me how to choose my provision profile which I have already created specifically for my application. Its really consume my whole day.

Comment: Didn't get any right solution yet. Any help on this would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hello 
i faced the same problem, so did you solve it ?
if yes please can you tell how ? 
and thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 6 - How to pick signing certificate/provisioning profile for Ad-Hoc distribution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056144/xcode-6-how-to-pick-signing-certificate-provisioning-profile-for-ad-hoc-distri)

Comment: Don't forget to mark the correct answer @Sathish

Answer (score 2):

Xcode wanted to automatically sign with the default "XC com.*" wildcard provisioning profile instead of the explicit profile that already had.

To fix this, I just re-generated the profile on the Apple Developer Portal:

1) Go to developer.apple.com and find the distribution provisioning profile you want to use.
2) Select it, click "Edit", re-name the profile, and click "Generate".
3) Download the provisioning profile to the Desktop and drag it onto the Xcode 6 icon.
4) Re-start Xcode 6.
5) Open the organizer window and click "Submit" on the archive you built.  Xcode will automatically pick your explicit profile instead of the generic one.

Comment: I have newly created the code signing certificate, AppId, Provisional profile against my distribution profile but no luck for me even I did delete existing profile from my keychain.

Comment: In my case, I had picked the wrong app's app ID when I set up my provisioning profile - XCode doesn't tell you this, it just doesn't work. So when you have done these steps and "XC: *" is still showing, just double-check your provisioning steps.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode 7 try to select "Use local signing assets" when selecting team. In my case it automatically selected custom Ad-Hoc profile, instead of XC Ad-Hoc*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite tricky but in your app build settings, you don't have the good provisioning and/or the good code signing identity for the archive mode (RELEASE) and maybe be the bad team too. You have to re set all this things and re archive. You know it's good when Xcode show the good certificate.

Hope you will export your application.

Answer (score 0):

**Organizer -> Export** worked for me as Organizer -> Upload to App Store and Validate were picking Xcode generated provisioning every-time.

Similar topic discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056144/xcode-6-how-to-pick-signing-certificate-provisioning-profile-for-ad-hoc-distri/34154426#34154426).