# Selecting a provisioning profile for Ad Hoc Distribution in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode6, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

Having issues doing this.

It will NOT let me select the provisioning profile to use, instead it defaults to some XC Ad Hoc: * and I cannot change it.
The correct profile is selected in the build settings.

I get:

[image: Default Provisioning Profile]

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the same issue in Xcode 6. I fixed it by:

1. Go to Apple Developer > Create a new App ID specifically for the app with Explicit App ID like com.mywebsite.MyApp. Don't choose Wildcard App ID option.
2. Go to Provisioning Profiles > Distribution > Update App ID (for MyApp) to the new one I just created.
3. Generate a new profile.
4. Download and install.
5. It doesn't hurt to Clean before Archive.
6. Go to Organizer > Export > Save for Ad Hoc Deployment. Xcode will give me an error on the first attempt. I had to click Try Again. That's when it started to pick up the new profile.

Also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056144/xcode-6-how-to-pick-signing-certificate-provisioning-profile-for-ad-hoc-distri) might be helpful. Good luck.