# Error: Invalid Token for push notifications to App loaded through iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, push, itunes

When I load the APP using Xcode, push notifications work nicely, if I load it on the device using iTunes, push notifications do not work: I always receive a "[1] Invalid token" error when trying to sent a push notification to the device from backend.
I noticed the pushId app receives in the two cases (loaded through Xcode/loaded though iTunes) are different.

Perhaps when loading the app through iTunes it automatically receives a production pushId? If this is the case, is it possible to load the app through iTunes so that is has a development pushId?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly resolved: XCode 6 contains a bug, exporting the .ipa file with the incorrect provisioning profile, so the pushId generated is invalid.
How to export with the correct provisioning profile is described here:
[Xcode 6 - How to pick signing certificate/provisioning profile for Ad-Hoc distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25056144/xcode-6-how-to-pick-signing-certificate-provisioning-profile-for-ad-hoc-distri)